# Escaping HTML when UPDATE MySQL Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to escape the string bellow (Text + Youtube HTML IFrame):
**HTML Form to Database**

```
$maq = TEXT  TEXT  TEXT  TEXT  TEXT  TEXT  TEXT  TEXT +
<iframe width="300" height="265" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0Ek2ayXgniw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

To Update a MySQL Table:

```
$sql = "UPDATE maquinas SET 
        maq = $maq,
        WHERE id = $id";
require 'connect.inc';
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql,$connection) or die ();
```

I tried these following PHP functions before MySQL Update:

```
htmlentities($maq);
addslashes($maq);
htmlspecialchars();
mysql_real_escape_string($maq)  **this before $sql_result**
```

None escaped HTML.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Important to note, mysql_* is deprecated in favor of PDO or mysqli_* both of which will handle this parameter properly.  Make sure you're storing things like HTML in a column capable of fitting it (like TEXT)

Comment: Your question is not very clear, what are you trying to escape the html for: The database, html output, etc.? And `mysql_real_escape_string()` should be used **before** you build your `$sql` string. By the way, using PDO or mysqli you could use prepared statement and you would not have to worry about database escaping.

Comment: I used PDO to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use mysql_real_escape_string on $maq only (before merging the parameters into $sql). It prepares the values for the database. This means, it escapes all dangerous chars like ", ', etc. < and > are not affected, because they don't affect the mysql command.
BTW, you shouldn't use mysql_*. It is deprecated. It's better to user mysqli_* or PDO.